# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0

Tags: java, hibernate

Im new to hibernate, and not quite sure what is wrong with my application. 
So i have these 2 modules: Core and Website.

- Module core has all the entities, daos and all database work. all DAOs inherit an AbstractDAO.
- Module Website does all the front end stuff like jsps, mvc controllers... It is a maven module that supports spring framework.

Im trying to implement second level cache using ehcache factory. however i'm receiving this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The error appears when I add logback-classic.jar, but if i remove it i receive another error.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/selector/ContextSelector
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>       at com.before90.website.action.application.ControllerServlet.doService(ControllerServlet.java:28)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)

I don't know why the error is appearing. it shows that there is a spring framework error, where spring is not implemented in module Core ( where all the DAOs are). Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

If you are using hibernate-validator, in my case, I just added one more dependency as below: (because javax.xml.bind will not be available on classpath by default in JAVA 9 and above, please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html
)

[image: validator need one more dependency]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can use `hibernate-validator 5.2.2` (for Hibernate 5) with Hibernate 4. Try to use `hibernate-validator 4.2.0.Final`.

And there are two `ehcache` jars in your class path!

Try to use Maven or Gradle build to get valid dependences.

Comment: @S.H. Do you fix ehcache version?

Comment: yes. Removed one of them and kept the one with version 4.

Comment: @S.H. Try to use `hibernate-entitymanager 4.2.2.Final` and `hibernate-ehcache 4.2.2.Final`

Comment: @S.H. It is strange that you use `logback` may be you need to use `commons-logging`.

Comment: I tried these as well :( By the way do we need spring to use 2nd level cache?

Comment: @S.H. You don't need Spring to use a cache. I think, you need to go from the other side. Please, create a simple console `gradle` project and add Hibernate and cache dependences, other dependences will be loaded by `gradle` as transitive. You will see libraries list you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all require dependency

```
    <!-- JSR 303 Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove logback-classic.jar,
Instead the root cause seems to be the missing definition for org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl 
As per Google, you need to include http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator
If its a maven project then the below config in your pom dependencies shall make things work smooth for you

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
```

Comment: But I already have hibernate-validator jar in my Core module, and the class  ConfigurationImpl  is already there.

Answer (score -5):

The problem was with the WAR only.

Comment: It will be helpful to everyone who faces a similar problem if you give more details of what exactly was the problem and how you resolved it. Your answer is too vague.

Comment: The war file was missing a whole module, so I had to add it manually to the war file. you can do this by adding the missing module's compile output to the war output